# Add node to KendoUI TreeView does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am researching the Kendo TreeView widget from the documentation. I am trying to add a predefined node (which is a div with some input elements) to a TreeView structure. This is the example I follow:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/api.html

I am able to append the node only once and it disappears. I am not very familiar with jquery and javascript so any help with working example will be greatly appreciated. Here is jsfiddle sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/MwHNd/454/

To reproduce the bug, try to add the node with AppendNode button several times. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 treeview.append($("#text"), selectedNode);
```

to

```
treeview.append($("#text").clone(), selectedNode);
```

The issue is you are appending the same element so it get detached and re-atached.